# Centre Item in RelativeLayout inside DrawerLayout

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have a Drawer Layout that contains a relative layout for the main activity within it as well as a custom application bar library. I am trying to center the placeNameDesc TextView within the screen, however this is not occurring

XML layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:anroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".PlaceDetails"
    android:background="@mipmap/background">

    <com.github.florent37.awesomebar.AwesomeBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="4dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bar"
        android:id="@+id/placeImage"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/placeImage"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/menuYellow" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/placeNameDesc"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:layout_below="@id/placeImage"
        android:textColor="@color/menuYellow"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/placeNameDesc"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/menuText"
        android:id="@+id/placeName"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/placeAddressDesc"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Address:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/placeName"
        android:textColor="@color/menuYellow"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/placeAddressDesc"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/menuText"
        android:id="@+id/placeAddress"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/placeRatingDesc"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Google Rating:"
        android:layout_below="@id/placeAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/menuYellow"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/placeRatingDesc"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/menuText"
        android:id="@+id/placeRating"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/submitInstructions"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/instructionsButton"
        android:src="@drawable/instructionsbutton"
        android:background="#00000000"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/submitInstructions"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/submitinstructionsbutton"
        android:background="#00000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I'm not sure if RelativeLayout is the correct layout type to be using here, any help with this problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set this attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`
and to remove `android:layout_below="@id/placeImage"` from its attributes because this attribute places it below `placeImage` and does not allow it to center properly.  
You may have to make other changes after this to the other views.

Answer (score 0):

Hello MrJimmyBoy the issue in your layout is you are providing a kind of anchor to your textview to align with in addition with `layout_centerInParent`.

Providing suc tags `layout_below` or `layout_above` etc will override  `layout_centerInParent`, `layout_centerHorizontal` and `layout_centerVertial`

All you need to do is remove `android:layout_below` from your `placeNameDesc` Text View.